# How to get the a href clickable and get his own ID in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
<table class="datagrid-btable">
   <tbody>
     <tr id="datagrid-row-0">
        <td field="username"></td>
        <td field="firstname"></td>
        <td field="lastname"></td>
        <td field="actions">
            <div>
               <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="editrow" id="1"><span>EDIT</span></a>
               <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="deleterow" id="1"><span>DELETE</span></a>
            </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="datagrid-row-1">
        <td field="username"></td>
        <td field="firstname"></td>
        <td field="lastname"></td>
        <td field="actions">
            <div>
               <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="editrow" id="2"><span>EDIT</span></a>
               <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="editrow" id="2"><span>DELETE</span></a>
            </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>       
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.editrow').on('click', function() {
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

**Question:**

I don't know much of jquery. But I tried I also tried this code: `$('.editrow').closest('td')` still nothing. Maybe someone who's pro in this can help me.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I will edit the question again. Sorry. But my question is that i want to get the id of the a href of edits.

Comment: your `console.log` is missing a close parenthesis. Otherwise what you've got should work.

Comment: You got it right. Just include closing braces for `console.log`statement.

Comment: @aldrin27 That's not a question, that's what you want to do. How about you explain what you expect to see and what you're actually seeing

Comment: @pratikwebdev still nothing.

Comment: @Phil there's no error but the a href is not triggering the console.

Comment: My guess is the script is in the page `<head>` (or otherwise in the document before the `<table>`) and not wrapped in a *ready* handler. See the duplicate question above.

Comment: @Phil the js is at the bottom of my head above the end of body.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: @aldrin27 I'm not sure what that means. `<head>` comes **before** `<body>`. Did you have a look at the duplicate question and answers?

Comment: @aldrin27 Refer to my answer. You need correction of `id` and event associated with class name `editrow` and `deleterow` I have replaced `console` logging with alert for easy testing. You can handle it anyway you need.

Comment: @aldrin27 you also have duplicate IDs which is a big no-no although that shouldn't stop your code working.

Comment: @pratikwebdev maybe this is because of my plugin. I use the plugin of jeasyui. Maybe the DOM is not yet ready but it is wrap in the _ready_ function.

Comment: @Phil they same ID's but different actions.

Answer (score 0):

```
  console.log($(this).attr('id');
```

to:

```
 console.log($(this).attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your script at the end of `<head>`, you **should** wrap it like this,

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.editrow').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

If you don't wrap it with ready function, the script will try to bind the event handlers before the DOM exists.

Otherwise, put your script at the end of the `<body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.editrow').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
</script>
```